# Change value in cell if value in dataset matches value in a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> dput(m1)
structure(list(Person_ID = c(111L, 222L, 333L, 444L), City = c("New York", 
"Los Angeles", "Paris", "New Delhi")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

However, I want to change the city name if the Person_ID is contained in a vector, such as this:

```
> dput(Person_ID)
"333,444"
```

For Person_ID 333 and 444, I would like to change BOTH of their cities to San Francisco.
The final dataset should look like this:

```
> dput(m3)
structure(list(Person_ID = c(111L, 222L, 333L, 444L), City = c("New York", 
"Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "San Francisco")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

My real dataset is quite large, so I would prefer not to do this manually

Comment: Try `m1$City[m1$Person_ID %in% c(444, 333)] <- "San Francisco"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is tricky because there is a `Person_ID` in the Global environment and a column in the data.frame with the same name, which makes it a little harder to use NSE like we may normally do with `dplyr`. To remove ambiguity, we can reference the `Person_ID` vector from the global environment with `.GlobalEnv`, or use the double bang sign (`!!`) instead.
Using the same example data from @Gregor Thomas' answer, to make it clearer:

```
library(dplyr)
m1 |> mutate(City = replace(City,
                            Person_ID %in% .GlobalEnv$Person_ID,
                            "San Francisco"
                            )
             )

# OR

m1 |> mutate(City = replace(City,
                            Person_ID %in% !!Person_ID,
                            "San Francisco"
                            )
             )

  Person_ID          City
1       111      New York
2       222   Los Angeles
3       333 San Francisco
4       444 San Francisco
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going on with the row names of your data frame in your sample data. I changed them to be `1:4` so the sample would create correctly. Then we need to break apart your string of Person IDs into a vector, and finally the assignment is easy using `data[rows, column] <- new value`:

```
## fixed row names
m1 = structure(list(Person_ID = c(111L, 222L, 333L, 444L), City = c("New York", 
"Los Angeles", "Paris", "New Delhi")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:4)

Person_ID = "333,444"

# turn Person_ID into an integer vector
person_vec = strsplit(Person_ID, ",") |> unlist() |> as.integer()

m1[m1$Person_ID %in% person_vec, "City"] = "San Francisco"
m1
#   Person_ID          City
# 1       111      New York
# 2       222   Los Angeles
# 3       333 San Francisco
# 4       444 San Francisco
```